# CSS max length in input type styling

Tags: html, css

How can achieve max length text in css "(100 char. max)" in the input text box[image]

Comment: Could you share the code you tried, so we can help you fixing it ?

Comment: Best way would be to wrap the input in a wrapper, and put a pseudo-element `::after` on top of said wrapper. Set the wrapper to `position: relative;` and absolutely position the pseudo-element as desired.

You have to use a wrapper as you can't place pseudo-elements on `<input>`s, and this way you can still position relative to the input.

Comment: put it in a div or something  with relative to the input

Comment: Why is it marked as duplicate ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a rough idea but with the following code you could achieve a similar layout to the one you have posted above.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

input {
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 0;
  outline: none;
}

span {
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

```html
<label>
  Description
  <div id="wrapper">
    <input type="text" placeholder="This is the description"/>
    <span>(100 char. max)</span>
  </div>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a div container and place an input and a div element in it with `display:inline-block`. Then remove the borders and add the border to the container. Then it will look like a single input element

```css
div{
  width:300px;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
div *{
  display:inline-block;
  border:0px;
}
div div{
  width:120px;
}
```

```html
<div class="inp">
  <input id="ip" />
  <div class="chars">100 Chars Max.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

There is no **maxlenght** property in CSS.
Use HTML **maxlenght** instead:

```
<input type="text" name="myInput" maxlength="100"/>
```

Comment: he want to style the `100 chars. max` text on the `<input>`.